# Unable to update Kotlin method parameter's value

Tags: methods, compiler-errors, kotlin, immutability

I've following Kotlin method

```
fun getpower(base:Int,power:Int):Int
{
    var result = 1
    while(power > 0){
        result = result * base
        power-- // <---- error in this line
    }
    return result
}
```

Kotlin compiler gives following error
`Error:(6, 8) Val cannot be reassigned`

What's wrong with updating the variable?

Answer (score 3):

> What's wrong with updating the variable?

The others answer the question by effectively saying "because Kotlin function parameters are immutable."  Of course, that is a(the) correct answer.

But given the fact so many languages, **including Java**, allow you to re-assign function parameters, it might be valid to interpret your question as "why does Kotlin disallow re-assigning function parameters?"

**My Answer**: Kotlin and Swift have many features in common, so I went to Swift 3 to see why **they** decided to deprecate function parameter re-assignment and found this [motivation](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0003-remove-var-parameters.md#motivation).

> Using  var  annotations on function parameters have limited utility, optimizing for a line of code at the cost of confusion with  inout , which has the semantics most people expect. To emphasize the fact these values are unique copies and don't have the write-back semantics of  inout , we should not allow  var  here.
>
> In summary, the problems that motivate this change are:
>
> • var  is often confused with  inout  in function parameters.
>
> • var  is often confused to make value types have reference semantics.
>
> •Function parameters are not refutable patterns like in if-, while-, guard-, for-in-, and case statements.

Of course, Kotlin has no `inout` decoration.  But the writers could have chosen to allow `val` and `var`, with `val` being the default.  Then they would have had behavior consistent with many other languages.  Instead, they opted for code clarity.

The OPs example code shows a valid example of when parameter re-assignment is clear and natural.  Having to add one more line to a very short function (to get a local variable to do what the parameter variable could have done) IMHO reduces clarity.  Again, IMHO, I would have preferred optionally being able to declare my parameters as `var`.

Answer (score 2):

A function's parameters inside the function are read-only (like variables created with `val`), therefore they cannot be reassigned.

You can see discussions about this design decision [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/function-parameters-are-val-not-var/897) and [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/method-parameters-and-mutable-variables/333).

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, method parameter's are **val(non-mutable)** type not **var(mutable)** type. Similar as java `final`.
That's why i cant **mutate(change)** that .

Comment: yes, you can think it as **effectively-final** in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The error you saw has more to do with scoping. A function's parameter by design is immutable or more accurately, read-only and that is what the `val` keyword stands for that is why you see that error.